# How to read a column as bytes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, utf-8

I have a pandas DataFrame whereby a column consists of strings as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df
       WORD         
0      '0% de mati\xc3\xa8res grasses'       
1      '115 apr\xc3\xa8s J.-C.'
```

For each string in the dataframe, I can read them as `bytes` by `b'0% de mati\xc3\xa8res grasses'.decode("utf-8")` and `b'115 apr\xc3\xa8s J.-C.'.decode("utf-8")`. I would like to ask how to decode this column. I tried `df['WORD'].astype('bytes').str.decode("utf-8")` but to no avail.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Your columns are currently strings that you wish to convert to bytes and then back to (properly encoded) strings? Or they’re initially bytes?

Comment: The column isn't bytes.  It is a string decoded incorrectly.  Can you fix upstream and decode the strings correctly as UTF-8 when read into the dataframe?  Perhaps show that code.

Comment: Hi @BallpointBen, my column is currently strings that I wish to convert to bytes and then back to (properly encoded) strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what the initial encoding is, but it looks like latin-1:

```
df['WORD'].str.encode('latin-1').str.decode('utf-8')

0    0% de matières grasses
1           115 après J.-C.
Name: WORD, dtype: object
```

Since the output seems sensical I'd say this is correct, but generally there's no surefire way to re-encode text if it has an unknown encoding to start.